# UITableView Center Cell Details

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uilabel, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am trying to sync a `UITableView` with a `UILabel` to make sure they show the same data; of course, things will be different in the end, but for testing this is what I need to do.

[image]

See the arrow? I want that middle cell (from px44-88) to show the `cell.textLabel.text` in a `UILabel` when it is the "middle cell".

I tried using `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` but I was having so many problems I figured I'd come here to ask if anyone has a better way of doing this. I'm not sure if it would make a difference or not but I am using `NSFetchedResultsController` to populate my `UITableView`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView, so probably you can use UIScrollViewDelegate

`- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView`

member to detect which cell is currently in the middle.

I.e. assuming you have a plain table with no sections, and tableView is an outlet for the table, label is an outlet for the label, than this will function in your controller will work:

```
    - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
        int row = (scrollView.contentOffset.y + tableView.frame.size.height / 2) / 44;

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0];

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        label.text = cell.textLabel.text;
}
```

Of course, you need to do some scrolling to make it work ;)

You can use visibleCells method to get layout of visible cells for non-plain table and use it to detect cell in the middle of the table.